# What's the difference between styled-components and styled-components/macro

Tags: styled-components

Sometimes I see slightly different imports

`import styled, { withTheme } from "styled-components/macro";`
`import styled, { withTheme } from "styled-components";`

Since they have the same functionality I cannot understand the difference between them neither can google anything that could help.

Answer (score 18):

In production styled-components generates unique hashes for css classes like `.eeZmbc` or `.ZzNLl`. These are used for saving space but are not useful for developers in development.

For semantic class names in development a [babel plugin](https://github.com/styled-components/babel-plugin-styled-components) exists. It generates names like `.Navbar__Item-sc-14eztoj-1` as in `.FileName__StyledComponent-generatedHash` to help us trace an element/style back to its source.

So if you use `create-react-app` you can use this plugin without ejecting and without adding it to `babel config`. You just have change your import from `styled-components` to [`styled-components/macro`](https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#babel-macro). A quick find-and-replace in you IDE will do the trick.

All the compile-time code transformation is handled by [babel-plugin-macros](https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-macros)

`babel-plugin-macros` defines a standard interface for libraries that want to use compile-time code transformation without requiring the user to add a babel plugin to their build system (other than babel-plugin-macros, which is ideally already in place).

Personally I add the babel plugins to the config file manually and use standard imports like `styled-components`.